How does a Pressurized Vapor Chamber Deflect Its Envelope?
I'm working on a radiator for space applications.
A working fluid is sealed within a teardrop-shaped metal envelope fixed at its lowermost point. I'm trying to calculate the deflection as seen above mathematically instead of through a static simulation.
At the moment, my simulation looks like this--my goal is essentially to make this, but accurately:
def angle(p):
  return np.pi/2 - np.deg2rad(0.0457*p**2 - 0.1524*p + 1.9167)
  #experimentally obtained from images of an actual prototype

def coords(r, h, p):
  angles = np.linspace(0, angle(p), resolution)
  mag_r = np.linspace(0, r+h, resolution)
  x = np.concatenate([-mag_r * np.cos(angles), mag_r * np.cos(angles)])
  y = np.concatenate([mag_r * np.sin(angles), mag_r * np.sin(angles)])

  return x,y

r = 3
h = 10
pressures = np.linspace(1, 40, 10)#psi
plt.figure(figsize=((9,6)))
for p in pressures:
  x, y = coords(r, h, p)
  plt.scatter(x, y, label = "P = " + str(np.round(p,2)) + " psi")
plt.xlabel("x (in.)")
plt.ylabel("y (in.)")
plt.xlim(-h-2*r,h+2*r)
plt.ylim(-1, 2*h)
plt.title("Deflection for R=" + str(r) +"in., H=" + str(h) + "in.")
plt.legend()
plt.show()


Note that the pressures plotted are exemplary (a guess), and my goal is to correct my calculation of the deflection based on the pressure. Also note, the radiator is assumed to be "fixed" at its lowermost point at (x=0, y=0)
Thus far, I've tried a "soda can" approach, assuming that the envelope is a thin shell, and equating the hoop stress caused by the pressure to Hooke's Law:
$$\sigma = \frac{Pr}{t} = \epsilon E \implies \epsilon = \frac{Pr}{Et}$$
where $P$
= Pressure, $r$
= radius, $t$
= thickness, $ϵ$
= strain, $E$
= Young's Modulus.
However, I'm unsure what assumptions I might be making in this equation, and how to use this calculated strain (if it's even correct) to plot my "deflected" envelope.
I also tried the following formula from Shigley's regarding deflection of a curved beam
$$\delta = \frac{FR^2}{AeE}\int_0^\pi (\sin{^2\theta}) d\theta + \frac{FR}{AE}\int_0^\pi (\sin{^2\theta})d\theta - \frac{2FR}{AE} \int_0^\pi (\sin{^2\theta})d\theta + \frac{CFR}{AG} \int_0^\pi (\cos{^2\theta})d\theta$$
$$= \frac{\pi FR^2}{2AeE} - \frac{\pi FR}{2AE} + \frac{\pi CFR}{2AG} = \frac{\pi PR}{2} (\frac{R}{E} - \frac{1}{E} + \frac{C}{G})$$
However, when I tried to implement it into code, I got some promising results, but am unsure how to integrate the deflection into my plotting.
for p in np.linspace(1, 60, 5):
  angles = np.linspace(0, angle(p), resolution)
  mag_r = np.linspace(0, r+h, resolution)
  x = np.concatenate([-mag_r * np.cos(angles), mag_r * np.cos(angles)])
  y = np.concatenate([mag_r * np.sin(angles), mag_r * np.sin(angles)])


  E=69e9/145038 #psi
  t = 0.02#in
  C = 2 #correction factor for thin-walled, round beam cross-section
  G = 30000 #psi
  deflection = np.pi * P * mag_r / 2 * (mag_r/E - 1/E + C/G)

I read this relevant paper (forgive me, I wasn't able to find a freely available version), which describes an approach for simulation, but I struggled to translate this into something I can model myself.
In doing my static simulation, it was found that for 1psi, there was a maximum deflection ~0.35", which is far off from the results of both of my equations.
Thank you in advance, please let me know if I can provide more information.

It is not clear to me what is the container being pressurised. Is the teardrop shape just a plate subjected to pressure from one side or is this plate actually hollow and pressurised from inside?

The plate is hollow and contains vapor which is pressurized.

If it were a circular tube bent into a U shape it would be possible to analyse it. But making it a rectangular tube with a high aspect ratio means you have to deal with the cross section changing shape as it inflates. Think of this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Party_horn As such I suspect a numerical simulation is your best bet

The straight part of the plate should just stretch due to pressure. The arc part could behave differently. The shape change needs to be caused by different deformation of internal and external plate in hoop direction.
Inputs

$P$ internal fluid pressure
$E$ Youngs modulus
$\nu$ Poisson ratio
$R_i$ mean internal plate radius
$t_i$ internal plate thickness
$R_e$ mean external plate radius
$t_e$ external plate thickness

Hoop stress in the external plate:
$$\sigma_{h,e} = \frac{P\cdot R_e}{t_e}$$
Hoop stress in the internal plate:
$$\sigma_{h,i} = -\frac{P\cdot R_i}{t_i}$$
(It may be more accurate to use surface radii where the pressure actually acts instead of mean ones.)
There will also be axial stresses, which you can infer from axial equilibrium (on an arc with angle $\varphi$, effect of short connecting walls is neglected):
$$\sigma_{a,e}\cdot t_e\cdot R_e\cdot \varphi + \sigma_{a,i}\cdot t_i\cdot R_i\cdot \varphi = P\cdot \left(\left(R_e-t_e/2\right)^2-\left(R_i+t_i/2\right)^2\right)\cdot \varphi$$
You have 2 unknown axial stresses at this point, so you need another constraint to resolve them. As a simplification, lets assume the axial deformation is the same for both walls, i.e.:
$$\epsilon_{a,i} = \epsilon_{a,e}$$
(To include the effect of straight parts, you may need to assume that their axial strain is also equal to this.)
Using Hooke's law ($\epsilon_x = \frac{1}{E}\left(\sigma_x-\nu\cdot \left(\sigma_y+\sigma_z\right)\right)$) and assumption of zero normal stress:
$$\frac{1}{E}\left(\sigma_{a,i}-\nu\cdot \sigma_{h,i}\right) = \frac{1}{E}\left(\sigma_{a,e}-\nu\cdot \sigma_{h,e}\right)$$
Now we have 2 equations with 2 unknown axial stresses. Stress in internal plate from the second equation is:
$$\sigma_{a,i} = \sigma_{a,e}+\nu\cdot\left(\sigma_{h,i}-\sigma_{h,e}\right)$$
Now put this into first equation (axial equilibrium):
$$\sigma_{a,e}\cdot t_e\cdot R_e + \left(\sigma_{a,e}+\nu\cdot\left(\sigma_{h,i}-\sigma_{h,e}\right)\right)\cdot t_i\cdot R_i = P\cdot \left(\left(R_e-t_e/2\right)^2-\left(R_i+t_i/2\right)^2\right)$$
Stress in external plate is:
$$\sigma_{a,e}  = \frac{P\cdot \left(\left(R_e-t_e/2\right)^2-\left(R_i+t_i/2\right)^2\right) - \nu\cdot\left(\sigma_{h,i}-\sigma_{h,e}\right)\cdot t_i\cdot R_i}{t_e\cdot R_e+t_i\cdot R_i}$$
Now you have equations for all the stresses and you can finally calculate hoop strains from Hooke's law:
$$\epsilon_{h,i} = \frac{1}{E}\left(\sigma_{h,i}-\nu\cdot \sigma_{a,i}\right)$$
$$\epsilon_{h,e} = \frac{1}{E}\left(\sigma_{h,e}-\nu\cdot \sigma_{a,e}\right)$$
If $\epsilon_{h,i}>\epsilon_{h,e}$, the shape should be opening in the desired manner due to fluid pressure $P$.
Edit:
There will be some resistance due to bending stiffness of the plates, which could be taken into account. All of the calculation above assume, that the distance between the plates remains uniform, which might not be the case in reality, where you could end up with highly increased or decreased plate distance at the center (or far from edges).
